# strange issue with select command in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I run the following query in mysql console:

```
SELECT * 
FROM has 
WHERE tweetId <= 32344308065509376 AND tweetId >= 31486746491363330
```

but record with `tweetId=32342160586047488` is not in the result set!!!!! but it exists in table "has"!
anybody can help me overcome this strange problem?
thanks

Comment: Does it show up if you do a `Where tweetId=323421etc...` directly? If not, then there's a parseing problem of some sort

Comment: http://ideone.com/ugS0m seems to disagree. Perhaps you could provide a full example, if this isn't one?

Comment: what is the data type of the tweetID column? I'm expecting it should be INT, but if it's a string, that could be your issue.

Comment: @dnagirl: That was my first thought, but testing those values against each other as strings gives the same results as numeric.

Comment: when I do where tweetId=32342160586047488 two rows was affected.

Comment: @user849727: Unable to replicate the behavior with a test table.  Maybe your table is busted.  Throw a `REPAIR TABLE has` at it, see if anything changes.

Comment: Thank you. it seems that the problem was solved by reapairing table "has".

Answer (score 0):

Either it's a parse error or your table needs repair.